# Problems with connection to Oracle from R

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc

I want to connnect to Oracle with R. I use RODBC package for this connection. Following is my code to connect

```
library(RODBC)

con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};
                         CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=123)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=abc)));
                         uid=abc; pwd=abc;")
```

But I get the following error

> 1:
>     [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>
> 2:
>     ODBC connection failed

It's really strange, because I use direct connection, it doesn't require no TSN nor DSN. Also I succesfully connect to Oracle with the same Hostname, Port, SID, Username and password, using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: I don't know if it will help but here is what I have : `connection_string <- 
  paste("Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=prdm;Uid=" ,userid ,";Pwd=",pw,";", sep = '')`

Comment: you need a tnsnames.ora in the `ORACLE HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN` directory check this http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora or switch to `rjdbc` package it's easier and you can do direct connection

Comment: run `cmd`, on the commend line check for `tnsping abc`, if not successful look at `tnsnames.ora` file and make your `sid=abc` in it, with correct port&host configuration.